# Como disponibilizar uma aplicação somente na minha rede sem fio?

Tags: servidor, redes, cliente-servidor

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e quero que ela só esteja disponível para os dispositivos conectados à minha rede Wi-Fi.

Eu até posso deixar rodando no meu computador pessoal e acessar via ip, algo como `192.168.1.20:8080`. Mas queria ir um pouco além e acessar através de um endereço, como `www.minhaaplicacao.com`. Logicamente, este endereço só irá existir internamente, então somente os dispositivos conectados à minha rede terão acesso.

A questão é, como? Eu vou ter que configurar o roteador? Não entendo quase nada de redes :/

Comment: Pra usar esse tipo de endereço você vai precisar de um servidor de dns, pra poder interpretar o ip da sua máquina como o endereço informado. Uma solução legal seria o uso do [no-ip], mas ele estará disponivel na web pra quem tiver o endereço que você criar lá.

Comment: Boa questão, acho que será muito útil pra muita gente. Não sei nada de redes também então não posso te ajudar. Mas acompanharei a questão. Fav e +1

Comment: Você vai precisar configurar um servidor de DNS interno, e acho que pra isso voce vai ter que configurar o seu roteador pra resolver esse endereco internamente. Então a resposta é sim, voce precisa configurar o seu roteador pra resolver esse dominio internamente.

Comment: Você pode comprar um TP-LINK N750 e mudar o firmware dele pra o OpenWRT. Você terá um router rodando Linux. O céu é o limite nesse caso. Você pode ter um servidor de DNS, servidor VPN, cliente VPN, iptables, etc. Mudar o firmware é uma questão de atualizar o firmware original, porém fazendo o upload do OpenWRT. Bem simples e fácil. Tem até uma interface web chamada LuCI.

Answer (score 5):

Roteadores mais robustos (com mais recursos) possuem opção de servidor DNS. Mas normalmente são roteadores mais caros e não é comum um usuário doméstico possuir.

De qualquer forma, verifique se o roteador ou modem que possui oferece tal recurso.

Alternativamente, o que pode fazer é montar um servidor DNS na sua rede local.

O processo é o mesmo que montar um DNS para a internet, só que nesse caso seria para uma intranet.
Isso seria para evitar ter que configurar todos os dispositivos um a um.

Caso queira algo mais simples, sem servidor DNS, apenas adicione o DNS fictício no arquivo hosts de cada dispositivo que pretende acessar a aplicação.

Exemplo,

A máquina onde roda a aplicação possui o IP 192.168.0.10

Na máquina pela qual pretende acessar, edite o arquivo hosts

Para Windows, abra o bloco de notas ou um editor de textos qualquer em modo "Administrador".

Usando o editor de textos, abra o arquivo:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Adicione a linha

```
192.168.0.10        www.foo.bar
```

Salve o arquivo. Pronto! Essa máquina vai enxergar o domínio `www.foo.bar` para o IP `192.168.0.10`.

Se quiser brincar mais pode inserir um domínio existente, yahoo.com, por exemplo, e veja o que acontece.

Para sistemas  Linux, o mesmo procedimento. Usando um editor de textos, abra o arquivo `/etc/hosts`, adicione o DNS e salve.

Para testar, em ambos os casos, faça um ping

```
ping www.foo.bar
```

O resultado deve resolver o nome para o IP `192.168.0.10`

Agora pode acessar a aplicação pelo nome. No browser, apenas digite na URL `www.foo.bar`.

Obviamente que a máquina onde roda o aplicativo deve estar com permissões liberadas de acesso a porta do aplicativo. Normalmente a porta 80.