# Aplicação Android em rede local

Tags: android, sqlite, redes, cliente-servidor, localhost

gostaria de saber por onde começar a estudar para criar um App que funcione em rede local. Tenho uma versão desse App que funciona usando o Firebase com minha base de dados online. Queria agora fazer algo parecido mas de forma local, com Wifi apenas Wireless LAN, onde você pode estabelecer conexões de soquete. Isso deveria funcionar também em qualquer rede LAN. Tem como fazer isso usando o banco interno do android? Tipo, fazer de um dos aparelhos o servidor com o banco de dados enquanto as outras servem como clientes? Como posso fazer isso para enviar dados como números ou strings?

Lembrando que meu objetivo é fazer isso entre Smartfones Android, sem usar um outro PC(notebook e etc) como servidor.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como disponibilizar uma aplicação somente na minha rede sem fio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109355/como-disponibilizar-uma-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-somente-na-minha-rede-sem-fio)

Comment: Diferente do que existe aqui no site tenho interesse que a aplicação se comunique em qualquer LAN que esteja conectada e não apenas e uma rede LAN especifica.

Comment: Penso que é ampla demais. Teria que fazer por partes. Um aparelho seria o servidor, com uma porta aberta, e os clientes varreriam a rede em busca dele. O que já vi ser feito é o aparelho servidor exibir na tela o IP em que está e esse IP ser configurado nos clientes.

Comment: Pesquisei bastante e achei a solução. Para o pessoal que chegou aqui procurando por como fazer algo assim no android, segue o link: https://androiddevsimplified.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/local-networking-using-nsd-network-service-discovery/